# JPA @OneToMany relation ERROR:table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

Am having two tables with primary keys. the name of the two tables are employeedefinition and employeeFldmapping with primary keys of employeeid and countrycode. 
I got the employeedefinition model by using the primary key.employeedefinitionpk  is the primary key model. the sample code is

**employeedefinitionpk emplpk = new employeedefinitionpk(employeeid ,countrycode);
 employeedefinition empdef = (employeedefinition) objprovider.find(employeedefinition.class,  emplpk );**

onetomany relation is there  between  employeedefinition and employeeFldmapping table.
 @OnToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumns({

@JoinColumn(name="empId",referencedColumnName="empId",insertable=false,updatable=false)})

protected List employeeFldmapping;

having the getter and setter methods

I try to get the employeeFldmapping from employeedefinition and iterate as follows

**EmployeeFldmapping  employeeFldmapping  = employeedefinition.getEmployeeFldmapping();

 for(EmployeeFldmapping emplFldMapping:employeeFldmapping){
 }**

But I got the following exception

**WARN - JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(100) |  SQL Error:942, SQLState:42000
ERROR - JDBCExceptionReporter.logException(101) | ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

kindly help me to get a solution for this

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure the user the application is connecting with has at least read permissions to employeeFldMapping?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. where i need to check this read permission.

Comment: `Select * from all_tab_Privs where grantee = 'USERID'  and table_name = 'EMPLOYEEFLDMAPPING'`  in your SQL tools try the above.  it will list any record with table name employeefldmapping for which the application user has access (change userID to application user ID).  If the application user is the same as the schema user you shouldn't have this problem.  however if the application user is different than the schema user then it may be  a permission issue. (check with a DBA if you have one) also `Select * from dictionary where UPPER(comments) like '%GRANT%'` to help with other analysis.